# Can't reply to user messages in android developer console

Tags: android

I've recently uploaded an android application on Google play, I was checking crashes and ANRs and I noticed that there was a crash report with a user message. The point is I want to reply to this message but I can't figure it out. I've searched for the answer in Google, but all the answers were how to reply to comments and ratings and not user messages in developer's console.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can reply to reviews on the following ways:

1. the [API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews)
2. [Google Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en)
3. Using the Play console app